# How to calculate value from a dynamically generated table and its rows using angular js?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to find the value for net worth from the table.

`Net Worth = Sum(Stock Price * Shares Held)`

Below is the table which is created as per user selection. [image: Table for stocks]

For ex: from the above table, Net Worth = (842.21*1 + 230.16*2 + 1002.2*2).

I am trying with ng-change as the networth can change every time the user adds or deletes stocks. Besides, I am also facing the css issue as networth goes down when a row is getting added to table.

[Here is the plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZlOQC9A4FZWZfowSMZee?p=preview).

```
  <section class="pickstocks">
    <label class="basiclabel">Manage Portfolio</label>
    <div class="pickstocks-align">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>STOCK</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                    <th>SHARES</th>
                    <th>WEIGHT</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="stock in stocksArray" class="portfoliokey">
                    <td>{{stock.key}}</td>
                    <td class="portfoliovalue">{{"&#x20b9;" + stock.value}}</td>
                    <td class="changer">
                        <input type="button" id="num1" ng-click="decrementValue( stock.index )" value="-">
                        <input type="button" id="number{{ stock.index }}" value="1" />
                        <input type="button" ng-click="incrementValue( stock.index )" value="+" />
                    </td>
                    <td>{{stock.weight}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="networth">
            <h3>Networth</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/89AaZYcugBUUlp3BU2CV?p=preview) for reference

The first thing to do is to store the `weight` field just like another field in the `stock` object.

```
mystock.weight = function(){return this.value*this.shares};
```

Making it into a function of the `shares` and `value` field lets us update the other two fields dynamically changing the `networth`. Also adding shares as a field to the stock object lets us update it easier later, so we only have to increment/decrement the field  like so.

```
$scope.stocksArray[$scope.stocksArray.indexOf(stock)].shares++;
```

The biggest part of changing the code was objectifying it. Taking the stocks and representing it with objects allows us to easily modify and access the values later.

Once that was done all you have to do is make a method that returns the sum of all of the weights like so.

```
$scope.getNetWorth = function(){
      let total = 0;

      for(let i = 0; i < $scope.stocksArray.length; i++){
        total += $scope.stocksArray[i].weight()
      }

      return total.toFixed(2);
    }
```

And then reference it in the html like so `{{"&#x20b9;" +getNetWorth()}}`

In the future try to use OOP practices to simplify your code and turn your data into object representations, it will save you time and headache trying to manipulate and access your data later.

Comment: Can you do using Angular JS?

Comment: I actually didn't know Angular until an hour ago, but after some quick study take a look at [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/89AaZYcugBUUlp3BU2CV?p=preview).

Comment: Mate how did you do this in an hour of study? You are genius man. Can you plz explain the logic for this? Besides plz edit the answer.

Comment: Fo sho, give me a moment to type it up.

Comment: Hey it has a css issue. Netowrth part goes down on adding new rows. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure, open that as a new question though and pm me the link.

Comment: Thanks mate for your time. But I was able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sure,is it related to this? If not then make a new question and tag me with @ in the comments.

Comment: @infamoustrey: this is a great answer, especially since you wrote it up, and then rewrote it for Angular upon request. Good work. However, be aware that a number of posters here will cheerfully ask you to do a significant amount of their work for them, so it is worth noting that sometimes asking for effort from their own side is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to calculate sum at each instance

```
 <tr ng-repeat="stock in stocksArray" class="portfoliokey">
                    <td>{{stock.key}}</td>
                    <td ng-init="totalAmount = totalAmount + (stock.value*stock.index)" class="portfoliovalue">{{"&#x20b9;" + stock.value}}</td>
                    <td class="changer">
                        <input type="button" id="num1" ng-click="decrementValue( stock.index )" value="-">
                        <input type="button" id="number{{ stock.index }}" value="1" />
                        <input type="button" ng-click="incrementValue( stock.index )" value="+" />
                    </td>
                    <td>{{stock.weight}}</td>
                </tr>
```

and total will be

```
<div class="networth">
        <h3>{{totalAmount }}</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any value printing for Networth. Can you help with a plnkr?